# Firebase realtime database: data keeps overwriting in the same node

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write data into my Firebase realtime database. This is my code:

```
firebase.database().ref("ac/0/").set(null);
firebase.database().ref("ac/0/").once('value', function(snapshot){
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        firebase.database().ref("ac/0/"+snapshot.numChildren()).set({
           "Current Date":arr[i][0],
           "EmpNo":arr[i][1],
           "Flag":arr[i][2],
           "Prev Date":arr[i][3],
           "Total charge":arr[i][4]
        })
    }
})
```

I expect the data to be inserted in new incrementing nodes, but it keeps overwriting in the same node. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Since `snapshot` never changes in your code, you're calling `set` on the same path each time - and that indeed writes to that same path, overwriting any previous data you put in there.

If you want to [store a list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data) of items in Firebase, use its built-in `push` method, rather than another mechanism:

```
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    firebase.database().ref("ac/0/").push({ // 
       "Current Date":arr[i][0],
       "EmpNo":arr[i][1],
       "Flag":arr[i][2],
       "Prev Date":arr[i][3],
       "Total charge":arr[i][4]
    })
}
```

I also recommend checking out: [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).